# currenttimestamp with timezone in sql server

Tags: sql-server, timezone

What is the sql server query to retrieve current time stamp with us/central time zone?

Answer (score 0):

You need both local and remote timezones, so Oracle can calculate the difference e.g.

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') 
AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'
FROM DUAL;

30.10.14 08:45:08,000000000 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

and

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') 
AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
FROM DUAL;

30.10.14 10:46:17,000000000 AMERICA/CHICAGO
```

You can get the list of timezone names with this:

```
SELECT tzname, tzabbrev FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;
```

so you can do this:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') 
AT TIME ZONE 'US/Central'
FROM DUAL;
```

assuming you are in New York.

Comment: is it currect to write like this
CURRENTTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE "US/Central"

Comment: @user3588496 In Oracle there is a dictionary view for all possible values: select * from v$timezone_names; As I know you can use both cols

Comment: i want to write it in sql not oracle.can you suggest me?

Comment: Oops, I saw the oracle tag but did not notice that you wanted it in SQL Server. So you can ignore/downvote this answer :)

Comment: can you suggest me how to write in sql?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea how to do that in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for SQL Server 2008 or above, this will provide the time at a specific timezone offset.  I don't know if you can provide a timezone name, and using this method, you'll have to handle daylight savings yourself.

```
declare @dt datetimeoffset = switchoffset(convert(datetimeoffset, getutcdate()), '-06:00')

select getutcdate() as utc, @dt as [datetimeoffset], cast(@dt as datetime) as [datetime]
```

Answer (score 0):

Time zone support was added with SQL Server 2016.  You can now do this:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
```

Note that the identifier `Central Standard Time` is the Windows time zone ID for Central Time in US and Canada.  It is inclusive of both CST and CDT.